# debian + plink on windows

Tags: debian, script, sh, mirc

i am working on a script on windows that should execute a debian .sh script when i get a [COMPLETE] line on my irc channel. But can't figure out where to put the line in my irc script.

so maybe if its possible to remove the sock stuff and online use plink, maybe it wil work better. im not getting any thing now, with the script.

```
on *:start:{
  window @somestuff
}
on *:TEXT:*:#CHAN: {
  if ($strip($2) == [COMPLETE]) && (*/* !iswm $strip($3)) {
    var %xxx $remove($strip($1),[,])
    var %xxx $strip($3)
    x %xxxx %rls
    aline @somestuff $strip($1-)
  }
}

alias x {
  var %autosockname $+(x.,$strip($2),.,$ctime)
  sockopen -e %autosockname IP ADRESS 443
  sockmark %autosockname $strip($remove($upper($1),[,])) $2
}

on *:sockopen:x.*:{
  if ($sockerr) { sockclose $sockname | halt }
  sockwrite -n $sockname GET /auto.php?fullpath=/path/to/file/ $+ $gettok($sock($sockname).mark,1,32) $+ / $+ $gettok($sock($sockname).mark,2,32) $+ &file= $+ $gettok($sock($sockname).mark,2,32) HTTP/1.0
  sockwrite -n $sockname Host: IP ADRESS
  sockwrite -n $sockname 
}

on *:sockread:auto.*:{
  var %auto
  sockread %auto
  if ([Auto] isin %auto || [Autofail] isin %auto) {
    msg #CHAN %auto
  }
  if (</html> isin %auto) { 
  sockclose $sockname }
}
```